# Multi-drop bus to rs232 Convert

Tags: serial-port, uart

I have a project using MDB (multi-drop bus) for vending machine (VDM).

The VDM has a MDB-RS232.

I'm not sure if it converts 9bit - 8bit (MDB-UART).

How do I read data from VDM in my computer?

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

MDB (multi-drop bus) is 9 bit, because after the standard 8 data bits (like in standard RS232 UART communication) there is a 9th bit called "mode".

([Wikipedia on MDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidrop_bus): "the mode bit differentiates between ADDRESS and DATA bytes.")

But you can read such data even with regular 8-bit RS232 interfaces, e.g. a plain standard USB-to-RS232 device for PC.

Here is how:

- Use 9600 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, but **RS232 parity setting "Space"**. Make sure you receive the original character value even in case of a Parity Error indication. Any MDB address byte from your VDM will be received with a Parity Error (but still be displayed correctly). Any data byte will be displayed without error.
- For sending MDB ADDRESS and DATA bytes using a standard 8-bit RS232 port, you could apply temporary parity changes: Change the parity setting to "Mark" before sending an address byte, then change back to "Space" before sending data bytes.

On Windows, you can do such tricks with our Docklight software (see [Docklight and MDB](https://docklight.de/dl_faq046/)). It's free for basic testing and there is also a related [9-bit example project](https://docklight.de/exampleFiles/extras/ParitySwitch_9BitProtocols.zip).

On Linux / Raspberry Pi other users have successfully implemented the parity trick, too, see this [stackexchange post about a MDB + Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38638/true-9-bit-serial-port-data).

But also with RealTerm, Teraterm, Termite, Bray, YAT or any other RS232 application you should be able to read the data, as long as it handles "Space" or "Mark" parity settings correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an adapter which will do all convert operations on-the-fly and in real time. If you want to emulate VMC (master), you'll need [MDB-UART master adapter](https://github.com/perdidor/Arduino-MDB-UART). If you want to emulate MDB peripheral device (such as coin changer, bill validator etc), you'll need [this](https://github.com/MarginallyClever/MDB-Sniffer). For two-way "sniffing" MDB bus you'll need a combination of these devices.
Direct connection PC's RS-232 to MDB will not work due to strict MDB timings (delay between VMC command and peripheral response must not exceed 5ms, delays between POLL requests are 50-300ms in general). I mean pretty reliable functioning available for commercial purposes.

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!

Comment: follow links from my post above, they are GitHub URLs containing source files. Cheers.